# Unable to drag and drop workitems on board from one state to another

Tags: tfs

Unable to drag and drop workitems on the board in TFS2013 whereas manually able to change the status from one to another (example: In progress to Done etc.). It's not happening for all the users, only few not able to perform this. Is this sort of permissions issue? if yes, where would this need to be set to avoid the issue. Any ideas.

Comment: What you mean "Unable"? the work item can't move to another column on the board? the work item can move another column but the state not changed?

Comment: Did you get any prompting message or error info when the user is not able to change the status?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for work tracking permission, you could grant or restrict access to various work tracking features by granting users or groups specific permissions for an object, team project, or collection. Please double check [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

You could use tf command line to list two users' related permission. One could, another is not unable. This will narrow down the issue.

Another thing, instead of drag and drop work items on the board in TFS2013 to change work item status. Suggest you ask that user to change the work item status in the work item directly . He may lack of the related permission for that specific work item.